# How to rename an entity in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity, rename

I am surprised I havent found an easy way to achieve this. I want to rename a table with existing data in it.

For example:

```
class Person : Entity
{
   long PersonId;
   string name;
}
```

I would like to rename this to:

```
class Client : Entity
{
   long clientId;
   string name;
}
```

---

**What I have tried:**

- Simply renaming the class, and creating a migration. The migration drops the person table, and creates a new client table.
- Create migration first with: `RenameTable("Person", "Client");` This gives me:

> Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong.

Comment: Hmmm, User is a (SQL Server) reserved keyword, could you try with PUser instead of User, for example, to see if it's the real problem ?

Comment: Ah, no. I thought you meant just to change in the example. The actual name of the entites are completely different, I used Person and User originally just to give a simple example.

Comment: Then may you show the real code ? (Not all the entities, just the class declaration and the migration real command). Cause it might be a simple typo...

Comment: I ended up deleting the database, and creating a new migration from scratch - so I am afraid I lost the migration file :/ But I was pretty sure there were no typo - the migration I created was literally one line:  RenameTable("Person", "Client");